# Two Periodic Functions with Period 1

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, periodic-functions

I am currently studying for a graduate exam and I came across the following question:

Suppose that $f$ and $g$ are real-valued functions on $\mathbb{R}$ having period 1 and having continuous first derivatives. Prove that $f'(c) = g'(c)$ for some non-negative $c \in \mathbb{R}$

My initial approach to this problem was to use the mean value theorem for $f$ and $g$ to obtain certain values where both derivatives vanish. However, this did not prove effective in proving the desired result.

Any suggestions on how to approach this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would look at $h=f-g$.

Comment: Nice, that's a quick and painless way to approach this problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$0=f(1)-f(0)=\int_0^{1}f'(t)dt$ and $0=g(1)-g(0)=\int_0^{1}g'(t)dt$. Hence $\int_0^{1}f'(t)dt=\int_0^{1}g'(t)dt$. If $f'(c) \neq g'(c)$ for any $c$ between $0$ and $1$ then either $f'(t) >g'(t)$ for all $t$ in this interval or $g'(t) >f'(t)$ for all $t$ in this interval (by Intermedite Value Property of continuous functions). Do you see a contradiction?

Comment: Nice, I see where the contradiction comes in. However, how does $f'(t)>g'(t)$ or $g'(t)>f'(t)$ follow from the Intermediate Value Theorem?

Comment: I am applying the theorem to the continuous function $f'(t)-g'(t)$. If it takes both positive and negative values it must vanish at some point, right? @algebraicgeometer22

Comment: Oh I see; I understand the proof now. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @algebraicgeometer22 If you are satisfied you could consider approving the answer. Otherwise this will be listed as  an unaswered question.